# Backbone collections is not updating after adding wait: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

**Scenario**

I am making a contact manager using backbone. I have a form and when user enters data and press submit button then user's data goes to server and save it in database.

**Problem**

It does work until adding it to the database. However, I also want to update collection after it adds to the database. For this reason I am using following lines of code to update collection.

```
addContact: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.collection.create({
        first_name: this.$('#first_name').val(),
        last_name: this.$('#last_name').val(),
        email_address: this.$('#email_address').val(),
        description: this.$('#description').val()
    }, { wait: true });

    console.log(this.collection);
}
```

Above function does add data to database but it does not update collection. But when I remove `{wait: true}` then it does update this collection.

**Question**

Why `wait: true` does not allow collection to be updated and how can I make it work with `wait: true`?

**UPDATE**

I also added the callback function like follow

```
{wait: true, success: this.successCallback}
```

and added that function like so

```
successCallback: function (collection) {
    console.log('call back');
    console.log(this.collection);
}
```

but it shows nothing in console from this function?

**UPDATE 2**

error function screenshot

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

xhr screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem (and even the same code). At my back-end I had:

```
Contact::create([
'first_name' => Input::get('first_name'),
'last_name' => Input::get('last_name'),
'email_address' => Input::get('email_address'),
'description' => Input::get('description')
]);
```

It responded with status 200 OK, but my collection hadn't been updated. I googled a lot, but didn't find a solution.

My back-end code didn't return anything to the script, so I decided to test if returning smth will make a change.
So I updated my back-end code to:

```
$contact = Contact::create([
'first_name' => Input::get('first_name'),
'last_name' => Input::get('last_name'),
'email_address' => Input::get('email_address'),
'description' => Input::get('description')
]);
return $contact;
```

And now it worked!
In both cases the request responded with 200 OK, but only when it returned data it fired the 'success' event.

Hope that'll help you.

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked for me, but what I don't understand (even after looking at the annotated source http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-62) is why. I tried returning the object with a different ID (changing it on the server-side with a debugger) to see if that triggers the remove on reply, but that didn't make a difference. I'm still trying to figure out what exactly Backbone wants to trigger the element removal from the collection, and why a simple HTTP 200 isn't enough.

Comment: I've been fighting with this all afternoon, as much as i like jeffery ways tutorials, in trying to use this one to learn backbone, I've inadvertently had to learn enough laravel to try fix all the problems like this, its taken me 2 days  - mostly getting my head around laravel and finding the correct ways to do the backend rather than actually just learning backbone.... 2 for one special maybe, lol.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that though server accepts newly created model, it fails to respond with status 200. Also, I would advise you to check what happens in the `success` function inside `Backbone.Collection`, that will help you locate the problem more precisely.

Comment: First of all it does respond with status 200 OK after checking it in Network tab of chrome web tools. Secondly, I also added `success: this.successCallback` but it does not call this function at all.

Comment: you are right. there is some sort of error. when I add this error callback function `errorCallback: function () {
  console.log('error');
 }` it does show up error in console. But how can I find what the error is? Sorry I am new to backbone.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `error` works with three parameters. To make things simple, just log them all in the console.

Comment: I did that. I added the screenshot what I get above. I really have no idea where to find error in my above console.

Comment: Check `xhr` property, if there were any errors with XHR request. Also, server should return changed model, that's why parse can fail, ensure that server does that.

Comment: Server didn't return changed model, you can see that response is an empty string. That's why validation fails.

Comment: By modifying server code so it returns JSON object with updated model, or by passing `validate: false`. You can also check for `error` and `invalid` events on the model (that's Backbone events, not native events) to be sure, that error is there.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to return json data in my serverside php. childish mistake. Thanks alot for you help.